# Unresponsive git status, diff, add (hanging)

Tags: git, bitbucket, ubuntu-16.04

The following git commands hang (do not respond) in one of my repositories:

```
git status
git diff
git stash
git add
```

The fact that I cannot `git add` leads me to believe that the unresponsiveness isn't simply due to very large files. Since `git stash` also hangs, I don't think it's merely a problem with communicating with origin.

`git remote show origin` shows the expected remote URL. I'm working on a branch and have checked that it has not been renamed. (FWIW, the origin is hosted on bitbucket.)

All the above commands respond as expected in a different repo, so it's not due to the internet connection.

Any other tips for troubleshooting this?

Comment: What does `GIT_TRACE=1 GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=2 git status` show? Also have you tried `git -vvv`?

Comment: If you are using Windows, check to see if some Windows process has some file or files in that repository locked. If so, your `git` command will wait for that other process to release the lock, before proceeding. If that other process never lets go, Git never proceeds.

Comment: It responded after 15 minutes or so, and now responds immediately without delay. It's possible that some files were locked, as @torek suggested. @torek, i'm using Ubuntu 16.04 - any idea how to check for locked files?

@jojek, git -vvv returns "Unknown option". I'm using git 2.7.4. Your other suggestion returns the same as `git status` now that it's working...

Comment: Linux does not force locking onto unwilling programs, so the Windows case does not apply. It does, however, sound like some file had super-delayed access for some reason. Linux supports many kinds of file systems, including networked and clustered non-local files, and these can be delayed arbitrarily long (basically waiting for some server to respond); perhaps that was occurring here. It is hard to say more without having access to the system.

Comment: Please execute `git fsck` to verify the integrity of your repository.

Answer (score 21):

For whatever it's worth, try `git fsck` (as per one of the comments) then `git gc`. When running `git status` and `git commit`, they were hanging for me after processing a number of files; and running those commands fixed the issue. I don't know which command actually fixed the problem.

Comment: `git gc` helped a lot in my case.  I don't think `fsck` did anything because there weren't any damaged files.  gc seems to do a lot of cleanup: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-gc

Comment: In my case just running git fsck (saw some blob dangling printouts)  helped, then git status was pretty quick

Comment: Running `git fsck` took like 45 minutes for me on a large repo. At the end there was a list of a couple hundred `dangling commit 9e9e9e9e9e9e9e9e9ee9e9` (`dangling commit <hash>`) and `dangling blob <hash>` lines it printed out. I googled to find out what those are and found this. You might find it useful too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18514659/git-what-is-a-dangling-commit-blob-and-where-do-they-come-from/18515113#18515113.

Comment: Also note that `git gc` stands for "git garbage collection" and I *think* it deletes all of those "dangling commits" and "dangling blobs" that `git fsck` reported. Also, for anyone wondering, even though `git fsck` took 45 minutes for me, `git gc` took only 3 minutes.

Comment: Now that I've run those two commands, `git status` takes 0.9 seconds to run now (time it with `time git status`), instead of freezing for what seems like forever.

Comment: And another note: after running `git gc` then doing a `git commit`, I got a message to read and delete the log file in `.git/gc.log`, and in the log file it said: `warning: There are too many unreachable loose objects; run 'git prune' to remove them.`, so I ran `git prune` as well, then did `rm .git/gc.log` to delete that log file. Git said it wouldn't perform automatic garbage collection again until I manually deleted that log file.

Comment: Is it time to accept this amazing, life-saving answer? :D

Comment: git fsck hangs too :(

Answer (score 6):

> It responded after 15 minutes or so, and now responds immediately without delay.

With Git 2.20 (Q4 2018), you will at least be able to check that `git status` is doing *something* (instead of just hanging in there): it learns to show a **progress bar** when refreshing the index takes a long time.

See [commit ae9af12](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ae9af12287b2c37512f12c137173dde7ea5192a0) (15 Sep 2018) by [Nguyễn Thái Ngọc Duy (`pclouds`)](https://github.com/pclouds).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 4d87b38](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4d87b38e6c1a73dbe744a30b9b3cdf88e69de7b4), 19 Oct 2018)</sup>

> ### `status`: show progress bar if refreshing the index takes too long
>
> Refreshing the index is usually very fast, but it can still take a long time sometimes.
>
> - [Cold cache](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22756972/6309) is one.
> - Or copying a repo to a new place (*).
>
> It's good to show something to let the user know "`git status`" is not hanging, it's just busy doing something.
>
> (*) In this case, all stat info in the index becomes invalid and git
>       falls back to rehashing all file content to see if there's any
>       difference between updating stat info in the index. This is quite
>       expensive. Even with a repo as small as git.git, it takes 3
>       seconds.

Answer (score 4):

Execute **git fsck**. In my case, it has resolved the problem.

Answer (score 4):

For any newbies, mine was hanging on git add - I had forgotten I'd been doing pg_dumps and had left some large files in the directory. I moved them to a different directory and that solved it.

Answer (score 3):

Git may be building an index of untracked files.  After adding several thousand new files into a freshly cloned repository, `git status` appears to hang for more than 2 minutes, then responds:

```
It took 139.67 seconds to enumerate untracked files. 'status -uno'
may speed it up, but you have to be careful not to forget to add
new files yourself (see 'git help status').
```

If you have a similar situation, consider moving the untracked files out of the repository and confirm that `git status` is again responsive.

Answer (score 2):

In my case what helped was rebooting my computer.

Answer (score 1):

I found mine was because I removed /node_module from the `.gitignore` file. It was there in previous adds so once I re-added /node_module, git started working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I found mine was:

```
[status]
    submodulesummary = 1
```

After comment out this `submodulesummary = 1` configuration in `~/.gitconfig` file, `git status` run much faster.