# Getting random generic error with Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-admin-sdk

The following code works 99% of the time, but every once in a while fails with this rather generic error:

"GoogleJsonResponseException: Backend Error at warmCache (WarmCache:225)"

```
var page = AdminDirectory.Groups.list(
{
  customer:   'my_customer',
  maxResults: 30,
  pageToken:  pageToken
});
```

Has anybody else seen this?

Thanks for any tips or pointers.

Comment: I don't have a direct answer for your question, but I think reading the [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22756092/what-does-it-mean-by-cold-cache-and-warm-cache-concept/22756972) for the topic of warm cache could help you understand the error.

Comment: Thanks, but I am pretty comfortable with my caching logic.  I just wonder why the AdminDirectory call fails seemingly for no reason.